# File not found: Example.java

Tags: java

Я новичок в `Java`, пытаюсь скомпилировать свой первый файл `Example.java`:

```
class Example {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

  System.out.println("JAVA Drives the WEB.")

  }

}
```

Запускаю так:

```
C:\MyJava\javac Example.java
```

В консоли появляется ошибка:

```
javac: file not found: Example.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Пробовал

```
C:\MyJava\javac -cp . Example.java
```

результат тот же.

Путь  к папке `C:\MyJava`  прописан в переменной среды `CLASSPATH`.

Путь `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05` прописан в `PATH`.

В чем проблема? Выручите, пожалуйста.

Comment: В конце строчки поставьте ; - System.out.println("JAVA Drives the WEB.");
И старайтесь сами выявить причину, а среда разработки во многом Вам в этом поможет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте [ликбез](http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html). После внимательного ознакомления со статьей вопросы отпадут.

Answer (score 0):

В исходнике есть ошибка:

**System.out.println("JAVA Drives the WEB.") ;**  *//точку с запятой потеряли*

Надо указывать путь к файлу для компиляции:

C:\MyJava\**javac -cp . <*путь_к_файлу*>**\Example.java